# How to put dropdown select in the angular select with ng-change?

Tags: angularjs, html-select, ng-options, angularjs-ng-change

I put a directive to the dropdown, but when I select a state does not change the dropdown and ng-change.

```
<select class="slc-state" data-ng-model="state" data-ng-options="state.name for state in states track by state.id" 
data-ng-change="updateState();">
<option value="">Select State</option>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/PenIm3NdUHJgXxOdrXMf?p=preview

Comment: can you be more clear on what you want? I mean, the requirements

Comment: I put a dropdown select. but in the angular when I select an item, it does not load the dropdown. In plunkr, you can see the whole code. 
I made a directive, but it only works when you press the first time. When I select an item, the ng-change does not work in the dropdown.

http://plnkr.co/edit/PenIm3NdUHJgXxOdrXMf?p=preview